# I can see my external USB drive when attached to one PC, but not others

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive

I have two laptops and a desktop, all running Windows 10.

I have an external USB3 1tB harddrive, which only the desktop can see.

Not just in Explorer, but in Desik Management and MiniTools Partition Wizard.

Any ideas how I can make it visible to all? It is formatted as NTFS,

---

[Update] just to clarify - this has nothing to do with networking. I am attaching the drive via USB to each of the 3 computers

---

[Update] I sort of solved it by connecting it to a different PC and formatting it, but now I have another problem.

I have two laptops and a desktop, all running 64 bit Windows 10. The external drive is only visible from the desktop which formatted it.

By visible, I mean attaching it by USB cable (no networking) and looking for it with Windows disk manager and with MiniTools partition Wizard.

The drive letter (X:) is not allocated on any of the three PCs. The drive is an external 2tB USB 3 drive which was previously usable from all three PCs.

Any ideas what is wrong, and how to make it visible from all PCS again?

Comment: [net share / net view / net session / net file / net use - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/net-share.html)?

Comment: My aplogies (+1). Please let me update the question